# Entity Framework 6 Migrations: How to disable automatic Update-Database on Database initialize?

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

We have a project running EF6 and have now activated Migrations. The problem we have is that we ha a lot of Data that needs to be added to the database when it is created. This worked well until we needed to add data in the migration part so it is part becomes part of the SQL script. Because when we try and create a new database on our development machines the migration steps are done before the Initializer's seed method and some of the data in the migration step depends on that seed data.

Is there some way to just get the initial database, without any migrations, plus the Initializer's seed data? Or do we need to move the critical data to the InitialCreate mirgations Up method?

The production database will cannot be wiped at this stage and thus we need to add all new production data to the migration step.

---

**Edit:** In the end we just moved the effected data to the Up method in migrations, not the way I wanted to do it but we where short on time and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Migrations also have a Seed method you can override that takes place after the Up() method. You can use the AddOrUpdate command in case data may exist. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3

Comment: The Seed method in Configuration only runs after all the updates are done. So if I do `Update-Database -TargetMigration: InitialCreate` with no database present then the database will be created but the Seed method is not executed.

Comment: Are you talking about the Seed method in the database initializer or the seed method in the migration? The docs on the migration seed method say "The purpose of the Seed method is to enable you to insert or update test data after Code First creates or updates the database. The method is called when the database is created and every time the database schema is updated after a data model change."

Comment: I'm talking about the seed method in the migration. The weird thing is that I have read what you just wrote as well but in the Seed method this comment was auto generated: `//  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.`

Comment: The Seed() method in the configuration.cs under the migration folder should run every time you do a database-update - even if the model hasn't changed. Just tried it on my end.

Comment: Really weird only runs for me when I do a Update-Database to the latest version. Are we on different versions or something? since we use different commands for update. According to NuGet I'm using EF 6.1.2

Comment: Sorry, my typo. I run update-database as well. Any messages in package manager console? Mine shows "No pending explicit migrations" followed by "Running Seed method"

Comment: Did some more testing and I have this behavior:
`Update to any of last three migrations -> Seed runs, Update to any other migration -> Seed does not run`

Comment: If it were me, I would just delete the migrations in the folder and database and do a fresh one. Then you can comment out the Up() code for the objects that already exist in the database, do the UPDATE-DATABASE and you will be in sync again for future changes. You could use the VS 2013 schema compare to sync PROD. http://www.techbubbles.com/sql-server/schema-compare-for-sql-server-in-visual-studio-2013/